# C++ Compilation error with std::cout and doublification macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm compiling the following in MSVC 2012

```
#define DOUB (i) ((i)+(i))

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i(0); i <= 10; i++)
        std::cout << "twice" << i << "is" << DOUB(i) << '\n'; // 22

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

and getting the following error for line 22 : **error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor macro definitions care about whitespace: Don't leave a whitespace between the macro name and the parentheses for function-like macros:

```
#define DOUB(i) ((i)+(i))
//      ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You left a space after `DOUB`. As far as your compiler is concerned, your code reads as:

```
std::cout << "twice" << i << "is" << (i) ((i)+(i))(i) << '\n';
```

You shouldn't blame the preprocessor, just avoid it! (or delete the space)

For completeness, what you created is called a **text replacement macro**, but you won't be using macros anymore will you?